# Customizing django admin add form

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Here is my models.py:

```
# customer table
class Pcu(models.Model):
  cust_id = models.IntegerField('Customer ID', primary_key=True)
  f_name = models.CharField('First Name', max_length=30)
  l_name = models.CharField('Last Name', max_length=30)
  # ... other typical fields follows

# pawn record
class Pwn(models.Model):
  pwn_no = models.CharField('Pawn No', max_length=13, primary_key=True)
  p_date = models.DateField('Pledge Date')
  amt = models.IntegerField('Amount')
  cust_id = models.ForeignKey(Pcu, db_column='cust_id')
  # ... other fields here...
```

Relationship is straightforward: a customer (Pcu) will have many pawn records (Pwn) but a pawn record is associated with only one customer.

With `django.admin` magic: the add Pwn form has `cust_id` field which is a select box and it has the list of customers added already. That's ok when the list is short, but in my case its quite big having few thousands of customers. So what I wanted is to add three custom fields: first name and last name each with its own text box and a filter button which on clicking shows only the matching customers in the `cust_id` select box. And the third field is a label which shows the selected customer address. How to do this?

Note: I am a new django learner using django v1.6 with Python v2.7 on SmartOS v0.147. Database is PostgreSQL 9.3

Comment: Have you considered creating a custom view within the admin for this? It'll be a lot easier and cleaner.

Comment: Could you please point some links which helps me create custom view within the admin?

Comment: Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites and a blog post about it. http://www.stavros.io/posts/how-to-extend-the-django-admin-site-with-custom/